# Join and Group using DynamicQuery

Tags: java, sql, liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

I have an SQL query:

```
Select t1.*
From tracking As t1
Inner Join (
    Select Max(trackingid) As trackingid, shipid
    From tracking
    Group By shipid
) As t2 On t1.trackingid = t2.trackingid
```

How can I execute this query using `DynamicQuery`?

Comment: AFAIK I don't think you can convert this sql query into `DynamicQuery` but you can instead use Custom-SQL finder for running this query. Or else you can convert the query to use sub-query which can then be converted to a `DynamicQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Aggreed with Kumar. You cannot use JOINS in dynamic query.
Its better to use custom-sql or finder query.